# Wrong date returned by JS when parsing ISO string sent by Dart

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I have a funtion that sends an `ISO` date string to a node.js rest API. However, when the date is parsed with in the js `Date` object, it returns a different date. I've also tried to send it in other formats like `.toLocal()` and `.toUtc()` with the same result.

**Flutter (Dart)**

```
  ///
  /// SEND DATE TO NODE.JS ENDPOINT
  /// 
  void sendDate() async {
    DateTime date = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);

    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.encodeFull('${config.domain}/sendDate'),
      headers: { "Content-type" : "application/json"},
      body: jsonEncode({"date": date.toIso8601String()})
    );

    print("Sent date");
    print(date.toIso8601String());

    print("Received date");
    print(response.body);
  }
```

**Output**

```
I/flutter (14203): Sent date
I/flutter (14203): "2020-01-01 00:00:00.000"
I/flutter (14203): Received date
I/flutter (14203): "2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"
```

**Node.js (Javascript)**

```
api.post('/sendDate',(req,res)=>{
  console.log("Sent date")
  console.log(req.body.date)

  const date = new Date(req.body.date);  

  console.log("Parsed date");
  console.log(date);

  res.send(date);
});
```

**Output**

```
Sent date
2020-01-01T00:00:00.000
Parsed date
2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z
```

As shown above, the date parsed by Javascript is one day less than the date sent by flutter.

**P.S:** As stated above, i've sent it in other formates like locale and UTC. Also no timezone configuration has been added.

**EDIT:** The date returned is actually an hour less. **i.e** sending `DateTime(2020, 1, 1, [2])`, will return `DateTime(2020, 1, 1, [1])`.

Comment: Are you in EST timezone?

Comment: No i'm not. =>  West Africa Standard Time Time zone in Ikoyi II (GMT+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to JavaScript's only in-spec [date/time format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format), the string `"2020-01-01 00:00:00.000"` is invalid (it should have a `T`, not a space, between the date and time). (Indeed, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations), a space isn't valid in ISO-8601, either, though it's a common implementation extension.) But V8 (the JavaScript engine used by Node.js) is okay with that, it'll handle a space instead.

Additionally, the string has no timezone information, so this part of the [date/time string parsing rules](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse) kicks in:

> When the UTC offset representation is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.

So you appear to be in a timezone that's at GMT+0100. Midnight on Jan 1st in Europe, West Africa, etc. (GMT+0100) is 11 p.m. Dec 31st UTC / GMT.

If you want that date/time interpreted as UTC, you need to add a `Z` to the end before parsing. To be completely within spec, replace the space with a `T` as well.

Comment: Alright thanks. But where do i place the `T` and `Z` respectively?

Comment: @KingsleyKbcComics - Refer to the linked specification for details. I've added "to the end" after "add a `Z` to it". I think *"...it should have a T, not a space, between the date and time..."* is fairly clear?